# Using Google Text-To-Speech in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-text-to-speech

I need to play **Google text-to-speech** in JavaScript. 
The idea is to use the web service:

> http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=This%20is%20just%20a%20test

And play it on a certian action, e.g. a button click.

But it seems that it is not like loading a normal wav/mp3 file:

```
<audio id="audiotag1" src="audio/example.wav" preload="auto"></audio>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function play() {
        document.getElementById('audiotag1').play();
    }
</script>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here is the code snippet I found:

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src ='http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=en&q=Hello%20World.';
audio.play();
```

Comment: It seems that if you remove the 'dot' at the end it works fine, otherwise it's not playing the sound.

Comment: Keep in mind that Google Translate has a limit of ~100 letters.

Comment: It seems that Google will ban requests with a Referrer in the HTTP header. Is there a way to bypass that issue?

Comment: @jichi Take a look on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25102474/713937) and comments to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5885535/713937).

Comment: As of today this doesn't seem to be working any more; I get 302 and then 403.

Comment: Can I use a text as a src for this tag. Ex: "Today is wonderful" this has to be spoken by the audio.play ?

Answer (score 168):

Another option now may be [HTML5 text to speech](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/01/Web-apps-that-talk---Introduction-to-the-Speech-Synthesis-API), which is in Chrome 33+ and [many others](http://caniuse.com/#search=SpeechSynthesisUtterance).

Here is a sample:

```
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello World');
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
```

With this, perhaps you do not need to use a web service at all.

Comment: The great thing about the HTML5 Speech Synthesis is that you can adjust the voice pitch, fluctuation, etc

Comment: Supported by Safari, IE?

Comment: You should add properties such as pitch, rate, speed, and etc.

Comment: @Rejaul Works in Chrome 76

Comment: This works on Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Opera and not on IE

Comment: It will work offline, because its natively supported by your browser.Though it's not as good as Google text-to-speech service, it worth to check it out. Found this link https://usefulangle.com/post/98/javascript-text-to-speech

Answer (score 22):

You can use the `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` with a function like [say](https://github.com/JudahRR/Say.js):

```js
function say(m) {
  var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
  msg.voice = voices[10];
  msg.voiceURI = "native";
  msg.volume = 1;
  msg.rate = 1;
  msg.pitch = 0.8;
  msg.text = m;
  msg.lang = 'en-US';
  speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
}
```

Then you only need to call `say(msg)` when using it.

**Update**: Look at Google's Developer Blog that is about Voice Driven Web Apps Introduction to the Web Speech API.

Comment: are you the same user as the JudahRR who wrote say.js?  If so, you should disclose that affiliation.  Also, probably no need to consume an external library for a 10 line function that just consumes the browser's native API anyway and doesn't need all of the default settings.

Comment: As this uses the google voices, is there any way to load other languages, like Danish?
I tried 'da' and 'da-DK' but she still spoke English.

I could use the other solutions here, but this options seem like the easiest one.

Answer (score 16):

Very easy with responsive voice. Just include the js and voila!

```
<script src='https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js'></script>

<input onclick="responsiveVoice.speak('This is the text you want to speak');" type='button' value=' Play' />
```

Comment: Important note here: Although this has interesting immediate results, it is using their API via `https://code.responsivevoice.org/getvoice.php` to generate voices and send them back as rendered audio. Their service is however not free for non commercial projects.

Answer (score 9):

The below JavaScript code sends "text" to be spoken/converted to mp3 audio to google cloud text-to-speech API and gets mp3 audio content as response back.

```
 var text-to-speech = function(state) {
    const url = 'https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/text:synthesize?key=GOOGLE_API_KEY'
    const data = {
      'input':{
         'text':'Android is a mobile operating system developed by Google, based on the Linux kernel and designed primarily for touchscreen mobile devices such as smartphones and tablets.'
      },
      'voice':{
         'languageCode':'en-gb',
         'name':'en-GB-Standard-A',
         'ssmlGender':'FEMALE'
      },
      'audioConfig':{
      'audioEncoding':'MP3'
      }
     };
     const otherparam={
        headers:{
           "content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        },
        body:JSON.stringify(data),
        method:"POST"
     };
    fetch(url,otherparam)
    .then(data=>{return data.json()})
    .then(res=>{console.log(res.audioContent); })
    .catch(error=>{console.log(error);state.onError(error)})
  };
```

Comment: this is the only answer that answers the question exactly

Comment: This answer is great, but how should I decode the given data, and how to use it

Comment: You can play the result for instance like this: const base64MP3 = res.audioContent;
const audioSrc = `data:audio/mpeg;base64,${base64MP3}`;
const audioElement = new Audio(audioSrc);
audioElement.play();

Answer (score 8):

I don't know of Google voice, but using the javaScript speech SpeechSynthesisUtterance, you can add a click event to the element you are reference to. eg:

```js
const listenBtn = document.getElementById('myvoice');

listenBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(
    "Hello, hope my code is helpful"
  );
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);

});
```

```html
<button type="button" id='myvoice'>Listen to me</button>
```

Comment: as of 2023 it doesnt work on chrome mobile. on firefox mobile it works.

Answer (score 3):

Run this code it will take input as audio(microphone) and convert into the text than audio play.

```
<!doctype HTML>
<head>
<title>MY Echo</title>
<script src="http://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family: verdana;
    }

    #result {
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #bbb;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 25px;
    }

    button {
        font-size: 20px;
        position: relative;
        left: 50%;
    }
</style>
```

Speech to text converter in JS
     
    
        var r = document.getElementById('result');

```
    function startConverting() {
        if ('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window) {
            var speechRecognizer = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
            speechRecognizer.continuous = true;
            speechRecognizer.interimResults = true;
            speechRecognizer.lang = 'en-IN';
            speechRecognizer.start();
            var finalTranscripts = '';
            speechRecognizer.onresult = function(event) {
                var interimTranscripts = '';
                for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; i++) {
                    var transcript = event.results[i][0].transcript;
                    transcript.replace("\n", "<br>");
                    if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
                        finalTranscripts += transcript;
                        var speechresult = finalTranscripts;
                        console.log(speechresult);
                        if (speechresult) {
                            responsiveVoice.speak(speechresult, "UK English Female", {
                                pitch: 1
                            }, {
                                rate: 1
                            });
                        }
                    } else {
                        interimTranscripts += transcript;
                    }
                }
                r.innerHTML = finalTranscripts + '<span style="color:#999">' + interimTranscripts + '</span>';
            };
            speechRecognizer.onerror = function(event) {};
        } else {
            r.innerHTML = 'Your browser is not supported. If google chrome, please upgrade!';
        }
    }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```