# Play custom sound with html and JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have just create a on small application.
Where user can login.

Now I would like to play sound like "Good Morning username" or "Good Afternoon username". I am able play mp3 file with if else as per time but not able to read a text.

Is it possible in HTML js or any other way on web?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Google Text-To-Speech in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653145/using-google-text-to-speech-in-javascript)  |  The accepted answer is related to using Google Translate but the answer with the most votes is the good one.

Comment: Here are some suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614059/how-to-make-python-speak

Comment: @FankaVasileva that's for Python, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [p5.js](https://p5js.org/) it has a load of libraries including [p5.speech](http://ability.nyu.edu/p5.js-speech/). This allows you to read text in a browser using javascript.