# Why this Javascript Text-To-Speech using Google URL does not work

Tags: javascript, html, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653145/using-google-text-to-speech-in-javascript) in stackoverflow. I tried to do the same but it does not work.

```
<html>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src ='https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=en&q=Hello%20World';
audio.play();    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Could you tell me what was wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a security feature Google has implemented for cross-domain protection.

It is still possible to do what you want though. Just make sure your rel tags are set up properly.

Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5885475/2542856) for more information.

Comment: `audio.rel='noreferrer'` I think you want `noreferrer`, not `nofollow`, but you can try either.

Comment: I tried "<audio id="ding" rel="nofollow" src="https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=en&q=Hello%20World" preload="auto"></audio>" but it doesn't work

Comment: also tried :
<audio id="ding" rel="noreferrer" src="https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=en&q=Hello%20World" preload="auto"></audio>, but it didn't work

Comment: Have you tried what I just added?? The JavaScript code?

Comment: Yes, It didn't work either. Why didn't you try it by yourself? only a few lines of code, save it into html file.